# Sorting Problems when using a list

Tags: python, sorting

I have a .txt file that contains a list of IP address:

```
111.67.74.234:8080
111.67.75.89:8080
12.155.183.18:3128
128.208.04.198:2124
142.169.1.233:80
```

There's a lot more than that though :)

Anyway, imported this into a list using Python and I'm trying to get it to sort them, but I'm having trouble. Anybody have any ideas?

EDIT:
Ok since that was vague, this is what I had so fair.

```
f = open("/Users/jch5324/Python/Proxy/resources/data/list-proxy.txt", 'r+')
lines = [x.split() for x in f]
new_file = (sorted(lines, key=lambda x:x[:18]))
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble" is mighty unspecific. What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: "I'm having trouble" isn't very useful; "I have tried X and it doesn't work in way Y and/or gives me the error Z" is much more so.

Comment: In which kind of criteria would you like to sort them? did you manage to even load the file, seperate the entry and putting them into the list object? where you at?

Comment: Wild guess: you're expecting the strings to sort numerically (so that 13 < 121) but they're sorting "alphabetically" (121 < 13)?

Comment: No, they aren't sorting at all......

Comment: To give us some sense of what you're talking about, show us what output you expect for the given 5 IP addresses, and what output you actually get for the given 5 IP addresses. Also, please explain where you got the magic number `18` from. Do you have more than one IP address per line in your actual file? What are you expecting the `.split()` call to do?

Answer (score 5):

You're probably sorting them by ascii string-comparison ('.' < '5', etc.), when you'd rather that they sort numerically. Try converting them to tuples of ints, then sorting:

```
def ipPortToTuple(string):
    """
        '12.34.5.678:910' -> (12,34,5,678,910)
    """
    ip,port = string.strip().split(':')
    return tuple(int(i) for i in ip.split('.')) + (port,)

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    nonemptyLines = (line for line in f if line.strip()!='')
    sorted(nonemptyLines, key=ipPortToTuple)
```

---

*edit:* The ValueError you are getting is because your text files are not entirely in the #.#.#.#:# format as you imply. (There may be comments or blank lines, though in this case the error would hint that there is a line with more than one ':'.) You can use debugging techniques to home in on your issue, by catching the exception and emitting useful debugging data:

```
def tryParseLines(lines):
    for line in lines:
        try:
            yield ipPortToTuple(line.strip())
        except Exception:
            if __debug__:
                print('line {} did not match #.#.#.#:# format'.format(repr(line)))

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    sorted(tryParseLines(f))
```

---

I was a bit sloppy in the above, in that it still lets some invalid IP addresses through (e.g. #.#.#.#.#, or 257.-1.#.#). Below is a more thorough solution, which allows you do things like compare IP addresses with the `<` operators, also making sorting work naturally:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import functools
import re

@functools.total_ordering
class Ipv4Port(object):
    regex = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})')

    def __init__(self, ipv4:(int,int,int,int), port:int):
        try:
            assert type(ipv4)==tuple and len(ipv4)==4, 'ipv4 not 4-length tuple'
            assert all(0<=x<256 for x in ipv4), 'ipv4 numbers not in valid range (0<=n<256)'
            assert type(port)==int, 'port must be integer'
        except AssertionError as ex:
            print('Invalid IPv4 input: ipv4={}, port={}'.format(repr(ipv4),repr(port)))
            raise ex

        self.ipv4 = ipv4
        self.port = port

        self._tuple = ipv4+(port,)

    @classmethod
    def fromString(cls, string:'12.34.5.678:910'):
        try:
            a,b,c,d,port = cls.regex.match(string.strip()).groups()
            ip = tuple(int(x) for x in (a,b,c,d))
            return cls(ip, int(port))
        except Exception as ex:
            args = list(ex.args) if ex.args else ['']
            args[0] += "\n...indicating ipv4 string {} doesn't match #.#.#.#:# format\n\n".format(repr(string))
            ex.args = tuple(args)
            raise ex

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._tuple < other._tuple
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._tuple == other._tuple

    def __repr__(self):
        #return 'Ipv4Port(ipv4={ipv4}, port={port})'.format(**self.__dict__)
        return "Ipv4Port.fromString('{}.{}.{}.{}:{}')".format(*self._tuple)
```

and then:

```
def tryParseLines(lines):
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line != '':
            try:
                yield Ipv4Port.fromString(line)
            except AssertionError as ex:
                raise ex
            except Exception as ex:
                if __debug__:
                    print(ex)
                raise ex
```

Demo:

```
>>> lines = '222.111.22.44:214 \n222.1.1.1:234\n 23.1.35.6:199'.splitlines()
>>> sorted(tryParseLines(lines))
[Ipv4Port.fromString('23.1.35.6:199'), Ipv4Port.fromString('222.1.1.1:234'), Ipv4Port.fromString('222.111.22.44:214')]
```

Changing the values to be for example `264...` or `...-35...` will result in the appropriate errors.

Comment: Remove all blank lines, comments and anything else in your data that doesn't look exactly like an IP:port address.

Comment: (Or better: add error checking / exception handling so that errors are handled gracefully. I leave this as an exercise.)

Answer (score 0):

@Ninjagecko's solution is the best but here is another way of doing it using re:

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('ips.txt') as f:
        print sorted(f, key=lambda line: map(int, re.split(r'\.|:', line.strip())))


['12.155.183.18:3128\n', '111.67.74.234:8080\n', '111.67.75.89:8080\n',
'128.208.04.198:2124\n', '142.169.1.233:80 \n']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pre-proces the list so it can be sorted using the built in comparison function. and then process it back to a more normal format.

strings will be the same length and can be sorted . Afterwards, we simply remove all spaces.

you can google around and find other examples of this.

```
for i in range(len(address)):
    address[i] = "%3s.%3s.%3s.%3s" % tuple(ips[i].split("."))
address.sort()
for i in range(len(address)):
    address[i] = address[i].replace(" ", "")
```

if you have a ton of ip address you are going to get better processing time if you use c++. it will be more work up front but you will get better processing times.

Comment: This would be better handled as a key function for `.sort()`. DSU (decorate-sort-undecorate) is not the best way to handle this in modern Python.